# How to separate integer inputs

Tags: java, input

I need to use scanner to get 2 inputs.
1st input is a sequence of integers that I need to store in ArrayList.
2nd input should go right after the first one and it's integer as well.
My question is  - how do I stop accepting input for ArrayList and tell the machine to ask for a second number.
I ended with something like this but it does not of course work because it just keeps asking for integers for arraylist. And yes, I need to use ArrayList for the task, since I don't know how many integers there will be. I also haven't learned List interface yet so I need to use what I have in my disposal.

```
   while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            numbers.add(scanner.nextLine());

        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            referenceNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        }
   }
```

Comment: Is the second input one integer or a list of integers too? Are you reading from a console or from a file?

Comment: only one integer. I'm reading from System.in (console)

Comment: Could you require the user to type the list on one line and the reference number on a second line? To read it you would then read the first line as a line and would have to separate it into integers afterwards, for example using a second `Scanner`.

Comment: Yes, that's totally what I need, actually, but I'm not sure how to do it. Do you mean that I just read the first line, split it into array of strings and then convert it to array of integers?

Comment: There are several good ways to do it. I was thinking `Scanner sequenceScanner = new Scanner(firstLineRead);`, then you can read integers off this second scanner the same way you do from the scanner in your code. Your own solution in your answer is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it this way, though probably not optimal

```
        String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] inputArray = inputString.split(" ");
        int[] numberArray = new int[inputArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            numberArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputArray[i]);
        }


        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            referenceNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your input sequence is something like 23 34 54 46 then you can use this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String integers = scanner.nextLine();
StringTokenizer string = new StringTokenizer(integers);
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(string.hasNextToken()){
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(string.nextToken()));
}
```